# Maven Fail integration test issue

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have integration test packages within my test source folder, i put them in a package called 'integration.com.....' and ended the integration class with IT prefix, however whenever i run mvn install it still runs my integration test, what i wanted to do was only run the integration test with a maven flag.

This is what i have added to my POM.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Maven's default lifecycle, the `integration-test` phase comes before the `install` phase.

To skip the integration tests, use the following on the command line:

```
mvn install -DskipITs
```

To have integration tests skipped by default:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Maven log showing that integration tests are being skipped when running `mvn verify`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17:integration-test (default) @ maven-failsafe-integration-tests-config ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17:verify (default) @ maven-failsafe-integration-tests-config ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Source: [Maven Failsafe Plugin - Skipping Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

Comment: Hi, i added <skipTests> flag, and im still getting the same issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output you get from Maven when running `mvn verify`. In particular, copy the lines where the first line starts with `maven-failsafe-plugin` and final line contains `BUILD SUCCESS` or `BUILD FAILURE`.